# Add Atributte Dynamically to Ruby Object

Tags: arrays, ruby, object, dynamic, yaml

I have the following class:

```
class Entity
  attr_accessor :name, :internal_asn_number, :classification_id

  def initialize(name = nil,int_asn_no = 0,classification_id = nil)
    @name = name
    @internal_asn_number = int_asn_no
    @classification_id = classification_id
```

Then I have a method that creates Entity objects dynamically from YAML files, however I would like that the field `:internal_asn_number` was dynamic too, it should go from 64512 to 65534 inclusive. For example, if the code only creates three Entities objects, then the field `:internal_asn_number` should have the values 64512, 64513 and 64514 for each object, respectively.

The code that I have is the following:

```
#map of yaml fields from entities yaml conf files
FIELDS = {'ENTITY_ID'.to_sym => 'entity_identification','NAME'.to_sym => 'name','CLASS_ID'.to_sym => 'classification_id'}

def load_yaml   
  path = /mf370/Desktop/entities_yamls/ 
  entities = Array.new
  Dir.entries(path).select {|file|
    if !File.directory? path + file
      if File.extname(path + file) == '.yaml'
        config = YAML.load_file(path + file)

        asn=*(64512..65533)
        asn.each do |number|
        entity = Entity.new(config[FIELDS[:ENTITY_ID]][FIELDS[:NAME]],"#{number + 1}",
                            config[FIELDS[:ENTITY_ID]][FIELDS[:CLASS_ID]])
        entities << entity
        end

      end
    end

  }
  return entities
end
```

This code gives me several issues in the output, the array of entities only has the last object saved several times, and it has the `:asn_internal_number` with the value 65533, the last number in the range.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Avoid looping the range of possible `asn_interal_number` values for each file; instead you could use a different variable to keep track of current `asn_interal_number` and check it before assigning the next; for example:

```
FIELDS = {'ENTITY_ID'.to_sym => 'entity_identification','NAME'.to_sym => 'name','CLASS_ID'.to_sym => 'classification_id'}
ASN_LIMIT = 65533

def load_yaml  
  path = "/mf370/Desktop/entities_yamls/"
  entities = Array.new
  current_asn = 64512

  Dir.entries(path).select do |file|
    if !File.directory? path + file
      if File.extname(path + file) == '.yaml'
        if current_asn > ASN_LIMIT
          puts "Error, maximum asn numbers reached"
        else
          config = YAML.load_file(path + file)
          Entity.new(config[FIELDS[:ENTITY_ID]][FIELDS[:NAME]],"#{current_asn}",
                              config[FIELDS[:ENTITY_ID]][FIELDS[:CLASS_ID]])
          entities << entity
          current_asn += 1
        end
      end
    end
  end

  return entities
end
```

The first thing you'll notice is the addition of a `ASN_LIMIT` constant, which is used to check if there are still asn numbers available.

```
ASN_LIMIT = 65533
```

And the addition of `current_asn` which keeps track of the las asn number assigned (initialized with the first possible value):

```
current_asn = 64512
```

And, finally the `asn` loop was replaced with another `if`, which prints an error if the `ASN_LIMIT` is reached, or assigns `curret_asn` value:

Next, `current_asn` is passed as a parameter to `Entity.new` (without any modification):

```
if current_asn > ASN_LIMIT
  puts "Error, maximum asn numbers reached"
else
  config = YAML.load_file(path + file)
  Entity.new(config[FIELDS[:ENTITY_ID]][FIELDS[:NAME]],"#{current_asn}",
                      config[FIELDS[:ENTITY_ID]][FIELDS[:CLASS_ID]])
  entities << entity
  current_asn += 1
end
```

Notice that the `current_asn` is incremented at the end, once it has been used to create a new `Entity`.

---

The following comments are not related to your question, but will make your code simpler:

You can change this

```
FIELDS = {'ENTITY_ID'.to_sym => 'entity_identification','NAME'.to_sym => 'name','CLASS_ID'.to_sym => 'classification_id'}
```

to

```
FIELDS = { ENTITY_ID: 'entity_identification', NAME: 'name', CLASS_ID: 'classification_id' }
```

and get the exact same result:

```
#=> {:ENTITY_ID=>"entity_identification", :NAME=>"name", :CLASS_ID=>"classification_id"}
```

In ruby is more idiomatic to create an empty array with `[]` rather that `Array.new`:

```
entities = []
```

Instead of `Dir.entries` use `Dir.glob`, and you won't need to check neither if file is a directory or it has correction extension:

```
Dir.glob("#{path}*.yaml") do |file|
  if current_asn > ASN_LIMIT
    # ...
  end
end
```

Comment: Thank you very much @Gerry, I'm new to Ruby programming and I really need to learn a different logic on how to program!!!! All the corrections to my code are very welcome!! Thank you again!

Answer (score 1):

I agree with previous answer but want to suggest write your own class like this one:

```
class Entity
  ASN_MIN = 64512
  ASN_MAX = 65533

  attr_accessor :name, :internal_asn_number, :classification_id

  def initialize(name = nil, classification_id = nil)
    @name = name
    @classification_id = classification_id
    set_internal_asn_number
  end

  private 

  def set_internal_asn_number
    @@last_free_asn ||= ASN_MIN
    raise 'No more free ASN number' if @@last_free_asn > ASN_MAX
    @internal_asn_number = @@last_free_asn
    @@last_free_asn += 1
  end  
end
```